# Polytopes-Discrete Geometry

Tags: discrete-geometry

Can someone help me solve the following question please?

Let v be a vertex of a d-polytope P such that $ 0 \in intP $ . 
Prove that $ P^{*} \cap \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^d  \mid\left < y, v\right>=1\   \} $ is a facet of $P^{*} $.

The definitions are:
$P^*=\{ y\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\mid\left < x, y\right>\leq 1\ \forall x\in P\} $
and a face of P is the empty set, P itself, or an intersection of P with a supporting hyperplane (i.e.- a hyperplane, such that P is located in one of the halfspaces it determines). 
A facet is  a face of maximal degree

I tried showing that if there exists a vertex v such that this isn't a facet, then P is a convex hull of a finite set not containing v, which is a contradiction, but without success.

HOpe you'll be able to help me

Comment: Have you tried any other proof directions that do not involve contradiction?

Comment: This analogy may help:  Suppose $P$ is determined by a minimal set of inequalities $f_i(x) \leq c_i$.  Then each set $P \cap \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \;|\; f_i(x) = c_i\}$ is a facet of $P$.

Comment: Actually, I've already thought of this analogy but without success...
I've also tried using the fact that 
$ P^* = \cap_{v \in V} D_0 (v) ^{-} $ where $D_0(v)^-= \{y \in \mathbb{R}^d | <y,v> \leq 1 \} $ .

Comment: Hope you'll be able to help me continue...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to see the property in dimension $n=2$ !